# Magento2 : I want to use admin theme from magento custom module controller

Tags: module, admin, theme, frontend

How can I use this url as `examplhttp//localhost/m2/seller/account/dashboard` (which is from my custom module `route/controller/action` ) to access admin like dashboard.

**i.e :** I want to use admin theme in frontend.